# Wheel RPM measuring reference point

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotation, angular-velocity

Attached is picture of a car wheel in 3D. Assume it is suspended and rotating in the air. If I put a nut + proximity sensor right on top of the nut within the red line to measure RPM, will the nut placement in point B and C have same RPM reading? What if it is placed in point A?

Point C is the surface of the wheel and point B is the side of the wheel. Point A is wheel center point.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the system works by counting signal pulses, then you can put it anywhere, except at the very center.

Wherever you place it, each time the wheel goes around, the nut crosses under the sensor and creates a signal pulse.  If one inch from the center, the nut crosses under the sensor once every revolution.  If you place it at the outside edge, the nut crosses under the sensor once every revolution.  You count the pulses in a minute and you get the rotations per minute.

Comment: That's what I thought too. Just needed confirmation. Thanks !